# How to subscribe to Firebase Messaging Channel

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried to subscribe to a topic and send messages to the channel but it is not working.

```
 Firebase.messaging.subscribeToTopic(topicName).addOnSuccessListener {
           
        }.addOnFailureListener {
           //failure case
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing `/topics/` before the channel name. So the solution is to add `/topics/` before the channel name.

**Final Code:**

```
Firebase.messaging.subscribeToTopic("/topics/"+topicName).addOnSuccessListener {
       
    }.addOnFailureListener {
       //failure case
    }
```